# Controlling visibility of a rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a application where I need to control the visibility of a rectangle ( and other elements) based on a float value. The nuget package I am using that generates the float value is always a float even though the data type I need is a Boolean (1 or 0) if the value is 0 I want the the rectangle to collapse

```
public void rectangleTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connector.Subscribe(DataRefs.Cockpit2RadiosActuatorsAudioSelectionCom1, 25, (element, value) =>
        {
            

            if (value == 0)
            {
                com1_rect_mon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        });




    }
```

When I try the code above it nothing happens, everything compiles correctly just the desired result of the rectangle collapsing does not happen. I have this in a DispatchTimer which is activated by a button, I have verified the timer is working by other means. I've been stuck on this for a few days and would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Have you verified that the visibility is actually changed? i.e. set a breakpoint inside the check? Besides, subscribing to something in a timer event handler is probably not the way to go.

Comment: @JonasH I am not sure I know what you mean. Inside what check?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint at `com1_rect_mon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`, is that breakpoint hit?

Comment: @JonasH Yes sir. I just learned about breakpoints but I added one at that line and it broke

Comment: Found the solution Dispatcher.Invoke(() => com2_rect_mon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => com2_rect_mon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed);` This is because the rectangle is on the UI thread.